# I am unable to get quickbooks api node.js sample inventory tracking to work

Tags: node.js, sample, quickbooks-online, inventory

I've ran both the hello world sample app and oauth2 sample app with out issue,
however when I try run the inventory tracking sample app and click connect it prints to console.

```
[Object: null prototype] {
    oauth_problem: 'parameter_rejected',
    oauth_parameters_rejected: 'oauth_consumer_key'
}
```

[image: img]

The only things I have edited, are the redirect in quickbooks keys to http://localhost:3000/callback
and public and private keys in config.json

```
module.exports = {
  consumerKey: '************', 
  consumerSecret: '*************',
  token:           '',
  tokenSecret:     '',
  realmId:         '',
  useSandbox:      true,
  debug:           false,
  //
  // Set useSandbox to false when moving to production. For info, see the following url:
  // https://developer.intuit.com/v2/blog/2014/10/24/intuit-developer-now-offers-quickbooks-sandboxes

  testEmail:       '',  // Use this email address for testing send*Pdf functions

  // //Plot.ly credentials
  username:        '',
  api_keys:        ''
}
```

thanks for your time :)

sample available here 
https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/SampleApp-InventoryTracking-QuickBooksV3API-NodeJS

Comment: Have you tried confirming the key and secret? Try copying the keys from the oath2 app config.js that you said worked and try again.

Comment: yes ive tried multiple times, I have deleted and re-installed the files, and i have refreshed and replaced my keys :\